# How to convert a batch of MP3's in Apple Music to AAC, then automatically delete the old MP3s?

Tags: file-conversion, mp3

I would like to convert a large number of MP3's in my Apple Music library to AAC (to save disk space).
Using the Music app, I have tried it with all songs of an album. Now, I've got each track twice, once in MP3, and again in AAC. That's very cumbersome to go through all songs and find the old mp3's.

Is there an easier way?

(I have googled, but did not find anything really useful.)

I converted the tracks as follows: I went to the album, selected all tracks in it, went to File  / Convert / Create AAC Version, and let Apple Music do the conversion.
That worked, but, as I said, afterwards, each track was duplicate in the album.

Comment: What did you use to convert your your MP3 to AAC? Do the output and original files have distinct extensions (.mp3, .aac)? If so, you can easily run a search for *.mp3 on the parent directory and delete all the results.

Comment: @slightly_toasted If both the AAC and the MP3 are part of the iTunes Library (visible in iTunes/Music), removing one of them via Terminal isn't a good idea

Comment: What do you need help with: converting tracks within Music, or getting rid of the duplicates?

Comment: I have the same problem, but in reverse. I've had iTunes (Music) save non-MP3 tracks into MP3 format to then burn the files to a CD which can be played on my car stereo, but they appear in the iTunes (Music) library, and I must use the iTunes (Music) interface to delete the dupes manually.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing.  Do you want to convert and remove the MP3s or has the conversion already been done and now you just want to remove the MP3s?

Comment: TNX, I have updated the description how i converted the tracks.

I need help with getting rid of the duplicates - or, better, with a process that removes the old mp3 version directly.

Comment: There are some iTunes duplicate scanner apps out there. Try searching for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this script](https://dougscripts.com/576) from Doug's AppleScripts website does exactly what I want.

> For macOS 10.15 and later only. Convert all or just the selected tracks of the selected Playlist using your choice of available encoders, restoring your Preferences-set encoder afterwards.
>
> Additionally, you can:
>
> - Choose to delete and/or Trash the original tracks and/or files
> - Copy all converted tracks to a playlist

Comment: Have you tried it out? is it safe? it must be 100% failsafe, so that I don't loose some tracks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app called [Adapter](https://macroplant.com/adapter) that will do batch convert but I'm not sure about the deletes. Since it's free it's worth a try. If it doesn't do the deletes you can always sort the files by kind so that all mp3s will be listed together in the Finder window.  Adapter also converts images and movies as well as sound files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used handbrake to do the conversion when I needed to do something similar - it has a simple text  file input to its batch processing.

I also found this when I was searching on google - there are lots of available solutions and I just started with one and edited it to my needs. I se4arched for things like "applescript to copy" etc

As a starter for you I have included a copy script I used:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
set source_folder to choose folder with prompt "Please choose the Source-Folder:" default location ((path to home folder) as alias)
            set source_files to every file in source_folder
            set target_folder to choose folder with prompt "Please choose the Taget-Folder:" default location (":Applications:" as alias)
            repeat with i from 1 to number of items in source_files
                    set source_file to (item i of source_files)
                    copy source_file to (target_folder) -- use "copy source_file to folder (target_folder as alias)" to copy the files
            end repeat
            set question to display dialog "  Files have  been moved.
    end tell
```

You can edit this as you wish for what you need.